# Automatically Copy Visible Cells Only

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to automatically. copy a column of values from one sheet to the other but I want it to only show the visible cells. So when I change the filter the copied product on the other sheet changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

So if i understand you want to copy only the displayed details from on worksheet to another.  Apply your filter, highlight the column, copy the data (Ctrl & C) . Go to the new sheet and paste should work.

[image: Sheet 1]

[!Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPHfi.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPHfi.png)

[image]

Comment: but I was hoping that on the first sheet you'd fill out the filter and then it would automatically change on the second sheet without filling out another filter

Comment: @PaigeHilliard Not possible without use of macros, With macros you would have to clear out the destination, cycle through the filtered cells, and insert them into the destination. Since I know the follow up will be, **how do I do this?** try to use the Macro Recorder feature of Excel which should do most of that for you